# For CDAP Logging HTTP RESTful API, how to pass filter parameter

Tags: logging, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

As per CDAP documentation a filter string can be supplied as an optional parameter. It will filter the returned log entries to those that match the supplied string.

https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/logging.html#http-restful-api-logging

How do i pass it in the rest api call ,if i need to filter on log level as error only. I have tried to add **&logLevel=ERROR** but it did not work, please guide me on how can we pass a filter.

Comment: Hi! This question appears a bit confusing to me. Are you actually using GCP product Data fusion? Because it is labeled like that but you are sharing documentation from CDAP (which runs underhood of datafusion but do not share REST API).

Comment: I am using CDAP documentation as the API documentation is not complete for GCP Datafusion. I am trying to use logging API to pull logs of a Datafusion pipeline specifically for error messages

Answer (score 1):

I think here there is some confusion about Data Fusion and CDAP.

As I tried to mentioned in my last message, Data Fusion and CDAP are not the same. Data Fusion is an independent product which is built on the open source project CDAP, but with [its own API](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/rest/) and tools/functionalities integrated in the Cloud.

If you want to view your logs, [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/audit-logging) you have the documentation for audit logs and [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/viewing-stackdriver-logs) you can search for pipeline logs in Stackdriver (another integrated product in the Cloud). These docs will guide you through the needed steps in GCP for what you want to search.

---

EDIT:

It appears to be actually possible to use CDAP endpoints for this matters.

@phaneendra shared a way to send API requests to [CDAP endpoints](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/logging.html#http-restful-api-logging) by navigating to System Admin -> Configuration -> Make Http Calls on your Datafusuion instance. This allows you to pull logs and resolve the posted issue.

Additionally, you can also use the documented [CDAP reference guide](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#logs_for_a_batch_pipeline) to create and manage your Cloud Data Fusion instances and pipelines.

Comment: I was able to use the Logging API to pull the Datafusion logs through REST API calls , it seems to be working even though its not officially documented.

Comment: @phaneendrakumar Could you expand a little more your answer? What API did work? What is not officially documented? I am curious about the resolution of this issue.

Comment: you can navigate to System Admin -> Configuration -> Make Http Calls
 on your Datafusuion instance , here you can send API calls and retrieve the data.
I was able to make the get request as mentioned in this documentation https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/logging.html#http-restful-api-logging and get the required log data

Comment: @phaneendrakumar Thank you! Now I better understand the issue and I will edit the answer to add your workaround to give it more visibility and for the sake of the community.